# GCM quickstart configuration file is forbidden to download

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i am trying to follow the GCM quickstart guide, but on step 2 it says "Your operation was forbidden" when i try and download the file with no other information obvious than the steps i have followed.

I followed some google link about going into console and enabling API services but i get the same error here "forbidden".

There is a button in console to "signup for free trial" for paid G.C.S. but i though GCM was free.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a network error? Perhaps try a different one and see how it goes. If you have firewalls or security that might be blocking it, that's something to check for too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Google Apps (Google for Work) Account you, or your account admin need to do the following steps:

- Open the Google Apps admin panel [admin.google.com](http://admin.google.com)
- Open the **Apps** menu item
- Open the **Additional Google services** menu item
- Ensure that the the **Google Developers Console** is **On** as in the following image:
  [image: Google Developers Console status need to be On]

Now you should be able to create your App for GCM.